# Printed page information and metadata within PDF file

Tags: pdf

I just opened my PDF file using the default PDF reader on Ubuntu, and when I tried to print it, the "Pages" box was already filled with "108-115". I was surprised, because that's the page number that I printed from this file last time, which was many days ago!

I wonder where the "last printed page information", or probably some other similar "metadata" of a PDF file, is stored. Is it in the PDF file itself, or is it somewhere else in the computer? (I'm asking this in general, not just specific to my case and Ubuntu, so I hope my question is not too specific.)

Ubuntu version: 12.04.3 LTS

PDF reader: Document Viewer 3.4.0

Comment: Please edit the question to include the version of Ubuntu and the desktop environment.

Comment: @DanD. I've added the version of Ubuntu and the PDF reader I'm using. (Not sure what you mean by desktop environment.)

Comment: Desktop environment refers to the desktop software you're using. There are many choices (it's Linux after all!). Some of the most popular ones are Unity, Gnome, KDE, and a bunch of lighter ones. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available for a pretty good list. Include the version number of yours as they change a lot over time.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, but how do I find out the desktop environment and its version?

Comment: Please see this [Q&A for more information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294285/where-are-evince-bookmarks-stored/294298). The answer is valid both for manual bookmarks and automatical ones (e.g. last page viewed).

Comment: @MikaH. That's a good question. Maybe someone here will give you a good answer. To start looking, open a console and type *ps -ef | less*. That will show you what's running on your system. Look through for tasks with names ending in "dm". I know KDE uses kdm and gnome (at least 2.x) uses gdm. I don't know what unity and others use. If you find any, you can Google them to see what package they're a part of.

Answer (score 1):

That information is not stored in the PDF.  I must be tracked by your pdf viewer.